# I have a jar with N unique balls. If I draw N random balls with replacement, what is the most likely number of duplicate draws?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have a jar with N unique balls. If I draw out N random balls with replacement, how many duplicate draws am I likely to have seen when I'm done? I.e., what is *the most likely number of times* that I will pick a ball I have already seen before?

Comment: An interesting question. What have you tried? Do you know how to find the probability of getting $0$ duplicates?

Comment: I think you can use expectation and linearity of expectation to get the correct value.

Comment: More exactly if you have a random variable X that defines the number of duplicates you take out then you can write $X = I_i + I_2 + ... + I_n$ where $P(I_1)=0$ and rest are equal $P(I_i)=\frac{i-1}{n}$. Hence $E(X) = \frac{n-1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

When exactly $k$ duplicates are seen, we must have drawn exactly $n-k$ unique balls.
Choose $n-k$ of the $n$ balls to be drawn in $\binom n{n-k} = \binom nk$ ways, and distribute the $n$ (ordered) draws among the $n-k$ (labelled) balls in $(n-k)!{n\brace {n-k}}$ ways.
Here, we've used [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Hence, the number of possible draws in which exactly $k$ duplicates are seen is

$$\begin{align}
D_k &= \frac{n!}{k!}{n\brace{n-k}}
\\&= \binom nk \sum_{j=0}^{n-k}{(-1)}^{n-k-j}\binom{n-k}j j^n
.\end{align}$$

Now, I'm not quite sure how to determine which $D_k$ is greatest for a given $n$, so maybe someone can take this further, or I might edit this later.